# Adding bank holidays to a sharepoint 2010 calendar programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, web-services, list, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I have a bit of hard task in that I want to be able to add bank holidays to a sharepoint 2010 calendar. I have read about using web services to update the calendar as the calendar is essentially a list. I have interacticed with lists programmatically before but have not really used web services to interact with lists in this case for interactiing with the calendar.

I have been doing some research on this but have not found a simple way to do this. I would appreciate if anyone here could share their knowledge on this and provide a simple way to do it or perhaps point me in the correct direction.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) method of the [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx).

Although the method name leads you to believe it is only for modifications, `UpdateListItems` is used for adding, deleting, and updating list items via web services.

Regarding adding items to a calendar, a calendar is like any other SharePoint list. However, it can be a little tricky if you plan to add recurring events. For an example of how to programmatically set the recurrence column values, see step 4 of [How to: Add a Recurring Event to Lists on Multiple Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434156.aspx).